# mariaDB see what users are deleted

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So this morning I was looking at our company's database users and it was a great mess, with some big potential insecurities. Since most colleagues where around I decided to gather them around and decide which users to delete.

Now I forgot one colleague uses powerbi and he wasn't around (a lot of different dashboards) and it will take some time for him te replace all the data sources with a new user. So I was wondering if there is anyway I can find the users I deleted so I can see which one was used by him since you cant see which credentials he was using in powerbi.

Comment: You don't have backups?

Comment: backups are for losers ;) but no, no user backups as far as I know. just the data is backuped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [general query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/) was enabled on your server, then you have a log of each query and the user that executed it.

Alternatively, enable the error log and set [log-warnings](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#log_warnings) to 1 or higher and then ask the user to try to refresh the dashboard. The access denied event will be logged into the error log.